# How to implement standalone GORM with latest libraries (spring 3, hibernate 4, maven 3)?

Tags: hibernate, grails, maven-3, grails-orm, spring-3

Although there is an example of standalone using of Gorm, libraries of it are a bit old.

Is there a tutorial with minimum configuration of using Gorm in a maven 3 project with spring 3, hibernate 4 without grails?

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible with grails a few grails 2.3.6 libraries :

```
@Grab("org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.0.0.RELEASE")
@Grab("org.grails:grails-spring:2.3.6")
@Grab("com.h2database:h2:1.3.164")
...
```

The rest of the example is here : https://gist.github.com/graemerocher/c25ec929d9bcd1adcbea

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to check [the Gormish project](https://github.com/danveloper/gormish). You can check the libraries in the [build.gradle](https://github.com/danveloper/gormish/blob/master/build.gradle) file.

Note that using the standalone GORM comes with some consequences:

- You will have a GrailsApplication instance
- This is tight to the servlet API
- 40MB~ of dependencies